# Bind Complex Json to Html Grid

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, kendo-grid

I am trying to render the complex Json array structure as html grid. I tried to used Kendo UI grid and Datatables.js to bind this json array but i am not quite sure how should i bind that.

Here is my Json.

```
{"data":[{"cemetry_record":{"info":{"application_id":"020.2009.00000004.001","cemetry_name":"Gore","cemetry_section":"Roman Catholic","service_type":"Burial","first_name":"david","middle_name":"charles","family_name":"smith","birth-date":"2000-01-01","date_of_death":"2015-01-01","service_date":"2015-01-01","last_modified_date":"2009-03-09T09:35:05+11:00","description":"Cemetry entry for david charles smith","Age":15,"Photos":"yes","lodgement_date":"2009-03-09T00:00:00+11:00","status":"deceased","formatted_application_number":"20.2009.4.1","contact_us_messsage":"contact us on 1234 for any details"}}}],"count":1,"pagination":{"previous":null,"next":null,"current":1,"per_page":10,"count":1,"pages":1},"error_list":null}
```

Can any one suggest how can i bind this data using Kendo UI grid Or datatables js or JPut plugin ?

**Update**
I got success in binding the grid using Datatablesjs. Still has some issues. Please see code below.

```
$("#example").dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("GetListJson", "Home")",               
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "cemetry_record.info.family_name" },
                { data: "cemetry_record.info.first_name" },
                { data: "cemetry_record.info.cemetry_name" },
                { data: "cemetry_record.info.cemetry_section" }
            ]
        });
```

The  `"@Url.Action("GetListJson", "Home")"`  returns the json format specified above.

The issue is datatables js expects paging parameters with certain name. Is there any way i can specify which json property to be used for pagination similarly how i have done for columns ?

Comment: That looks an awful lot like the response from a datatables ajax (Returned data on [this](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) page) call...? If so point a datatables [ajax](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) at it and it should consume it fine -  probably set [`serverSide` and `processing` to `true`](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html).

Comment: @annoyingmouse i am not really sure. This is the Json format that i need to deal with as i am not allowed to change this. I tried it with Datatables ajax but doesn't work.

Comment: Pretty sure it should if you point the ajax URI at the uri returning the data above. You might need to initialise the table and it's columns though. Perhaps work up a JSFiddle and we can have a further look?

Comment: @annoyingmouse Hey Thanks for your suggestion. It worked partially through. Paging is not working because it expects json properties with certain names. See updated questions and suggest a solution.